# React Flow-Router - How to navigate back without refreshing

Tags: javascript, meteor, reactjs, flow-router

I have started to rewrite my Meteor app with React + Meteor.
I am currently using Flow-Router as the Routing Framework for React.

IN the previous version of my app when I was using `iron-router`, when I click back on the browser, the page gets displayed very quickly without having to refresh.

However, I have noticed that with Flow-Router, if I click on the back button, the whole website refreshes.

Currently with Flow Router I only have 2 routes:

```
FlowRouter.route('/', {
    action: function(params, queryParams) {
        console.log("Yeah! We are on the /", params.postId);

        ReactLayout.render(Sidebar, {

        });
    }
});

FlowRouter.route('/managedata', {
    action: function(params, queryParams) {
        console.log("Yeah! We are on the managedata", params.postId);


        ReactLayout.render(Sidebar, {
            content: <ManageData />
        });
    }
});
```

What should I do to activate the 'history'??
So that when the back button is clicked it just renders the previous page without having to refresh just like `iron-router` does